# Using the union/intersection operators when accessing an index in array?

Tags: javascript, lodash

I have a function that uses lodash's [`template`](https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.15#template) method to dynamically create files and generate code within them.

Anyway, I encountered a bug that has me scratching my head. Googled around, couldn't find an answer.

Suppose I have the following array,

```
const myMap = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7];
```

What am I really accessing when I do the following?

```
console.log(myMap[1|4]); // 6
console.log(myMap[4|1]); // 6
console.log(myMap[4|1|4|1|1|1|1]); // 6
console.log(myMap[4|1|3|1|1|1|1]); // undefined

console.log(myMap[1&4]); // 1
console.log(myMap[1&5]); // 2
console.log(myMap[5&1]); // 2
console.log(myMap[1&6]); // 1

// combining the is also valid javascript, apparently:
console.log(myMap[5&1&5|2]); // 4
```

I feel like I'm missing something elementary, what's going on here?

## Edit

Likewise, I can do this with objects:

```
const obj = { hello:'world' }
console.log(a['hello' & '']); // undefined
console.log(a['hello' | '']); // undefined
console.log(a['hello' || '']); // 'world' (obviously)
```

Comment: `|` is a bitwise "or". https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Bitwise_OR. `&` is a bitwise "and" https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Bitwise_AND

Answer (score 1, accepted):

JS is evaluating the expression inside the square brackets, so for `myMap[1|4]` it evaluates `1|4` where `|` is a [bitwise OR](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Bitwise_OR), and `1|4 == 5` which is why you're getting `6 === myMap[5]`